# How to synchronize time with Firebase server in Java client?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to synchronize the time on a Java client application with the Firebase server, to prevent fails when the client system time is different from the server. Is it possible?

Here's my Firebase class code that starts the application:

```
    private static FirebaseOptions getOptions() throws Exception {
        /* ... */       
        for (Map<String, FirebaseOptions> map : credentials) {
            if (map.containsKey(uri)) {
                return map.get(uri);
            }
        }
        try {
            FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(getCredentials(uri))
                .build();
            /* ... */
            return options;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
    
    public Firebase(String projectId) {
        try {
            try {
                app = FirebaseApp.getInstance(projectId);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                FirebaseOptions options = getOptions();
                
                for (FirebaseApp fapp : apps) {
                    if (fapp.getOptions().equals(options)) {
                        app = fapp;
                    }
                }
                if (app == null) {
                    app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options, projectId);
                    apps.add(app);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = e;
        }
    }
```

I can request the server timestamp by HTTP request, but how to change the time in the Java client? I tried use the FirestoreOptions setClock, but it still uses the system time, and works only if the system time is ok:

```
        ZonedDateTime server = getServerTime();
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
        
        long offsetNano = server.getNano() - now.getNano();
        long offsetMilli = server.toInstant().toEpochMilli() - now.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        
        try {
            FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(getCredentials(uri))
                .setFirestoreOptions(
                    FirestoreOptions
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setClock(new ApiClock() {
                        @Override
                        public long nanoTime() {
                            return ZonedDateTime.now().getNano() + offsetNano;
                        }
                        
                        @Override
                        public long millisTime() {
                            return ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant().toEpochMilli() + offsetMilli;
                        }
                    })
                    .build()
                )
                .build();
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No error messages, but it still uses the system timestemp in firebase client. If the timestamp setted on the FirestoreOptions is wrong and the system clock is ok, it's connect, but if the setted clock is right but the system clock is wrong, no connect and returns the FirestoreException: com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata